# Expanding checkbox questions in CommCare case data export

Tags: commcare

I'm trying to create a case export in CommCare HQ of data collected via a CommCare mobile application. I've noticed that when I am doing a form export there is the option to expand the check box questions in the excel export of data. However I do not see the same option when I try to make an export of case data. Is there an option to expand check box questions when doing an export of case data from CommCare HQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default settings of your project do not let you split mulitselect questions in case exports. This is because your case does not know which questions correspond with which case properties (because it could be multiple questions).

However, we do have a feature preview that you can enable on your project that will allow you to define how you would like to split your case property in a case export.

You can enable this setting by going to https://www.commcarehq.org/a/your_domain/settings/project/previews/ and checking the "Split multi-selects in case export" option. Then hit Update Previews.

When that is enabled you should see an extra column in your export that will allow you to select the Type. Here you select "multiselect." Then you can add your options. Example below:

[image]